# Is there any command to exit R programming?

Tags: r

Is there any command that can be used to exit Rstudio by the console?(Similar to `exit` or `quit` in MATLAB)

Comment: (-1) the instruction to quit R is directly above the command prompt when you open R. *Type 'q()' to quit R.*

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes.  You can exit R with the `quit()` command.  More succinctly, the quit command is aliased as `q()`.

Normally when you start R, you'll be reminded of this command.  For example, in my install I see:

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.
```

See [docs here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/quit.html).

Answer (score 3):

Yes ,You have to use `quit()`

```
> quit()
Save workspace image? [y/n/c]:
```

Comment: I would redommend never to save workspace data, it is better that one makes sure to write reproducible code, that you run each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can exit through those commands from the terminal:

1. `q()` then [y/n/c] where y=yes, n=no, c=cancel
2. `quit()` then [y/n/c] where y=yes, n=no, c=cancel

please the [documentation](https://rdrr.io/r/) for further commands